# Scraping a website using requests and LXML in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, request, lxml, urlretrieve

I'm trying to scrape this website to retrieve the title and body contents ("Description" and "Features"), as well as the PDF link. However, when I attempt to extract the text using XPath `/html/body/center[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/font/text()`, I receive an empty list. However, as you can see in the following screenshot, there is a block of text after `/font`.

[image: i]

This is my code:

```py
import requests
from lxml import html
from urllib.request import urlretrieve


url = "https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/1060035/GME/PC817/1"

try:
    # Send an HTTP GET request to the URL
    response = requests.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()

    # Parse the HTML content of the page using lxml
    page_content = html.fromstring(response.text)

    # Extract the title using XPath
    title_element = page_content.xpath("/html/body/center[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/strong/font")
    title = title_element[0].text_content() if title_element else "Title not found"

    # Extract the body using XPath
    body_elements = page_content.xpath("/html/body/center[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/font/text()")
    body = "\n".join(body_elements) if body_elements else "Body not found"

    # Extract the download link
    download_link_element = page_content.xpath('//a[starts-with(@href, "/pdf-file/1060035/GME/PC817/1")]')
    if download_link_element:
        download_link = download_link_element[0].attrib['href']
        download_url = f"https://datasheetspdf.com{download_link}"
    else:
        download_url = "Download link not found"

    # Download the file
    file_name = "PC817_datasheet.pdf"
    urlretrieve(download_url, file_name)
    print(f"Title: {title}")
    print(f"Body:\n{body}")
    print(f"Downloaded {file_name} successfully.")

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to get by with pandas only, in order to get that table:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

df = pd.read_html('https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/1060035/GME/PC817/1')[2]
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
0   1
0   Part    PC817
1   Description 4 PIN DIP PHOTOTRANSISTOR PHOTOCOUPLER
2   Feature Production specification 4 PIN DIP PHOTOTRANSISTOR PHOTOCOUPLER FEATURES z Current transfer ratio （CTR：50%-600% at IF=5mA,VCE=5V） z High isolation voltage between inputc and output （Viso=5000V rms） z Creepage distance＞7.62mm z Pb free and ROHS compliant z UL/CUL Approved (File No. E340048) PC817 Series Description The PC817 series of devices each consist of an infrared Emitting diodes, optically coupled to a phototransistor detector. They are packaged in a 4-pin DIP package and available in Wide-lead spacing and SMD option. DIP4L APPLICATIONS z Programmable controllers z System appliances.
3   Manufacture GME
4   Datasheet   Download PC817 Datasheet
```

Pandas documentation can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/).

EDIT: to download the actual PDF file:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/1060035/GME/PC817/1')
intermediary_url = 'https://datasheetspdf.com' + bs(r.text, 'html.parser').select_one('a[href^="/pdf-file/"]').get('href')
r = requests.get(intermediary_url)
true_pdf_url = bs(r.text, 'html.parser').select_one('iframe[class="pdfif"]').get('src')
f = open('pdf_file.pdf', 'wb')
with requests.get(true_pdf_url, stream=True) as r:
    with open('pdf_file.pdf', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
print('done')
```

File will be downloaded as `pdf_file.pdf`, in the same folder as your running code.
For Requests documentation, go [here](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

This webpage is not well-structured, and therefore using XPath may not be the best approach. I would suggest [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) instead:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/1060035/GME/PC817/1"

response = requests.get(url)
html_content = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
rows = soup.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    th = row.find('th')
    if th:
        header_text = th.get_text()
        if header_text == "Part":
            part = row.find('td').get_text()
        elif header_text == "Description":
            description = row.find('td').get_text()
        elif header_text == "Feature":
            feature = row.find('td').get_text()
        elif header_text == "Manufacture":
            manufacture = row.find('td').get_text()
        elif header_text == "Datasheet":
            datasheet = row.find('a')['href']

print("Part:", part)
print("Description:", description)
print("Feature:", feature)
print("Manufacture:", manufacture)
print("Datasheet:", f'https://datasheetspdf.com{datasheet}')
```

---

Output:

```
Part: PC817
Description: 4 PIN DIP PHOTOTRANSISTOR PHOTOCOUPLER
Feature: Production specification4 PIN DIP PHOTOTRANSISTOR PHOTOCOUPLERFEATURESz Current transfer ratio （CTR：50%-600% at IF=5mA,VCE=5V）z High isolation voltage between inputc and output （Viso=5000V rms）z Creepage distance＞7.62mm z Pb free and ROHS compliant z UL/CUL Approved (File No. E340048)PC817 SeriesDescriptionThe PC817 series of devices each consist of an infrared Emitting diodes, optically coupled to a phototransistor detector. They are packaged in a 4-pin DIP package and available in Wide-lead spacing and SMD option.DIP4LAPPLICATIONSz Programmable controllers z System appliances.
Manufacture: GME
Datasheet: https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1060035/GME/PC817/1
```